# Peaceful Revolution

Tags: politics, geopolitics, future

In a prospective story I am writing that takes place between December 2027 and June 2028 of the Gregorian calendar, a future President of the Fifth French Republic named Édouard Wang, and his Prime Minister, Stéphane Lü, want to annex Quebec because they think it will be better treated by the French Government than by the Canadian Government.

But, President Édouard Wang and Prime Minister Stéphane Lü both have a hippie-like personality. So, they do not want to make a war declaration with true weapons. Instead, they want to organise swimming races, marathons, singing contests, and fighting video game tournaments. If Quebec loses, it must join the Fifth French Republic, if it wins, it will remain with Canada. The Peaceful Revolution began because people wanted the government to stop spending money on military operations killing other humans overseas (after some years, many people died from COVID-19 complications).

The June 1st, 2028, France won, and Quebec is now an Oversea region of the Fifth French Republic.

Could this Peaceful Revolution propagate in the entire world?

Comment: First, "How would X react to..." is a kind of question which is generally off-topic here, because it starts an open-ended discussion. Second, you didn't say a word about how this revolution went in France. Swimming races and singing contests won't change the form of government.

Comment: I have removed the question about "How would X react to...".

Comment: June 2nd, 2028: Quebec holds a referendum to emmancipate from France and become its own country. June 3: the referendum fails, mostly because Quebecois and French are no longer mutually intelligible. June 4: Quebec has a violent revolution and becomes its own country, Le Republique Livre d'Osti de Crisse et Tabarnak.

Comment: France wants to annex Qu**é**bec, OK. Her Most Gracious Majesty the Queen of Canada doesn't want to give it away. Wang and L**u** will be sorely disappointed; it doesn't matter what *they* want, it matters what *Canada* wants: and Canada doesn't do swimming video singing tournaments. (Canada offered to settle the matter with an ice hockey game, but France refused for some reason.) (Leaving aside the practical impossibility for a closeted agender person named Wangue, who nevertheless apparently prefers to be called Zeille, to become Président de la France.)

Comment: @AlexP the preposterous idea [upset Her Majesty for a bit](https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/queen-elizabeth-spent-night-hospital-palace-says-2021-10-21/) anyway

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Somehow the idea the HM the Queen will still have a voice in public affairs at the age of 102 is the *most* realistic thing about this scenario.

Comment: Could you clarify whether all those fun activities have binding consequences like losers have to join the French Republic and winners can keep their sovereignty?

Comment: You will get less downvotes if you delete the entire first paragraph.  Who the world leaders are is irrelevant to the actual worldbuilding part of the question and makes it sound more like a question about character choice than setting.

Comment: So what happens if France beats Quebec at nu metal and *Street Fighter 2*, says that Quebec is now part of France, and then Quebec tells them "no", possibly leavened with some of the vocabulary from The Square-Cube Law's comment? Do they have a way to *compel* Quebec to keep their word?

Comment: Err... but suppose the majority of Quebecois don't WANT to join France?  (Any more than the rest of Canada would care to rejoin Britain.)  You do realize that there is a significant Quebec independence movement, don't you?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868). Further, it's also a duplicate of [any number of questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+war+games) that ask "can games replace war?"

Comment: @jamesqf You know, the real question is how would the Canadians feel if some country offered every Canadian $1,000,000 USD in exchange for the country? The Quebecois might refuse the offer on principle of the offering country not speaking French, but me wonders.... :-)

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw -- June 5: Tired of the frivolity, Canada informs the Quebeckers that this whole "Fifth French Republic" thing is actually a Congolese internet scam and they should just resign themselves to being Canadians and occasional independence agitators.

Answer (score 2):

> Could this Peaceful Revolution propagate in the entire world?

No, it couldn't even happen where you said it did in real life.

But if it's a fantasy story where it did happen, then you can just say it works everywhere else and not worry about reality.

Answer (score 1):

### Open Source MAD (Mutually Assured Destruction)

It is not enough for France to want a peaceful war, Canada needs to want it to, and both sides need to want it bad enough that they would rather concede major territories or ignore what they see as major human rights issues than escalate to a conventional war.

In the near future, a hacker steals the complete instructions for how to make nukes or some similarly scary weapon of mass destruction, and as it turns out it's pretty darn easy once you know how.  What's more, he also steals the full CAD specs, chemical processes, and source code needed for making tactical missiles able to deploy them.  The thing is that this was not some government sponsored hacker who stole the information for his own country, and then keeps it secrete, he's a hacktivist who believes that all wars can be stopped if everyone has this knowledge.  So he makes this knowledge public so that every country, state, and testy billionaire now has the knowledge to destroy entire cities at their fingertips.  So pretty much over night, every nation becomes a nuclear power.  This makes conventional warfare pretty much useless because most nations are unwilling to fight a war that might escalate to nukes.

At first this does end all wars... but the peace is short lived.  Like putting a lid on a pressure cooker, the end of wars creates a building pressure as many nations start making more and more bold political moves believing they are safe behind MAD, as tensions rise, it soon becomes apparent that a global nuclear war is inevitable. So, the major nations of the world decide to force everyone into the MAD Pact.

Its rules are pretty straightforward: you join or you get nuked.  Neutrality on the matter is non-optional.  However, all those boiling tensions need an outlet; so, rules of non-violent engagement are formed. When two nations have a dispute, it it mediated by the member nations of the MAD Pact, and when mediation fails, competitive games are staged to resolve the issue.  By taking the price of human life off of the table, "wars" no longer escalate to the point where nukes become your last chance for survival.

So when France challenged Canada for sovereignty of Quebec, it is first brought up before the members of the MAD Pact.  If the nations can not decide by a major majority (like maybe 75%) that one nation or the other had a clear claim to the territory, then they must declare and judge games of dominance.  Everyone goes along with the games not because they all agree with them, or the outcome, but because not accepting the consequences of loosing games of dominance means expulsion from the MAD pact, which as I already said is non-optional... so really you concede your lose or get nuked out of existence.

Answer (score 1):

### No

### Why surrender?

The reason one nation might capitulate to another is not doing so is a worse option than capitulating. In a cold war setting, this kind of happened with NATO to the USA/SSA and Warsaw Pact states to the USSR/CCCP, due to pressure from both sides. In a world war setting, this would be because the country is occupied by a foreign army. The populace is then convinced, one way or another, to surrender.

### What is a peaceful revolution anyways?

However, this doesn't make sense in this revolution. If Canada loses the "peaceful revolution", Canada can just refuse to honor the loss. Based on the fact that France hasn't invaded Canada, Canada knows that they probably won't invade. Yes, defending is hard for Canada, but it is also hard for France to attack. This will make France unlikely to attack. Even if France does invade, then at least Canada is given a second chance. The same can happen in reverse.

### How could this happen?

Therefore if two countries are in a position to seriously consider this proposition they must already be in a position where they would consider incorporating into one state anyways. In that case, it would make more sense for the new state to make a constitution that lets the two countries, now one, to elect a new leader. If they instead settle this with the "peaceful revolution" then at least one of the countries is relinquishing it's political agency due to losing a game. If there is political deadlock, the two countries might agree to this, as a form of random tie breaker. It would also act as a propaganda for the unification.

### Controversial opinions below

Also, there are some states that would not even think of doing this. Do you think that Serbia and Croatia, Israel and Gaza, North and South Korea, or China and India would agree to this? Probably not. Win or lose, the games will be preamble to war. Also, if this became common, do you thing Russia wouldn't immediately challenge all of their small neighbors and annex them all?

### No, in conclusion.

While other nations may decide to unify as globalism increases it's hold on the world, this couldn't replace wars.

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithms and manipulation

Anyone following the news has seen extensive, albeit very shallow, coverage of social media algorithms and their alleged effects.  Your society has devised ways to make memes *catch on* that work better than anyone else's.  That means they control trillions of dollars worth of cryptocurrency and can buy anything they want - even Quebec.  Even *Google*.  They can make people *like* the idea.  And ... for the moment ... by some bizarre roll of the inheritance dice ... the power is in the hands of some people who **are not** determined to abuse it in a way that will rapidly and inevitably destroy the world.

I think people will have the most trouble suspending their disbelief when it comes to that last bit.